# django how to use Max and Count on the same field in back-to-back annotations

Tags: python, django

I would like to count the number of max `deployment__release_id` per `device_id`. I have the following:

```
release_breakdown = DeviceDeployment.objects \
    .values('device_id') \
    .annotate(release_id=Max('deployment__release_id')) \
    .values('release_id')
```

and it gives me what I expect which is a query set list:

```
<QuerySet [{'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 352}, {'release_id': 351}, {'release_id': 351}, {'release_id': 352}]>
```

How ever when I want to get the count of the above with:

```
release_breakdown = DeviceDeployment.objects \
    .values('device_id') \
    .annotate(release_id=Max('deployment__release_id')) \
    .values('release_id')
    .annotate(rcount=Count('release_id'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot compute Count('release_id'): 'release_id' is an aggregate
```

What I want is

```
<QuerySet [{'release_id': 352, 'rcount': 7}, {'release_id': 351, 'rcount': 2}]>
```

How can I get this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use annotate with annotated values.

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)

You should modify your query to be somenthing like this:

```
release_breakdown = DeviceDeployment.objects \
    .values('device_id') \
    .annotate(release_id=Max('deployment__release_id')) \
    .values('release_id')

count = Counter(i['realease_id'] for i in release_breakdown)
```

Should return a list like this:

```
[{'352': 7}, {'351': 2}]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't give me the count per `release_id` it gives me the number of of total rows in the `release_breakdown` queryset. Its the equivalent of doing `release_breakdown.count()`

Comment: Your are totaly right! Then you might have to use the collections! see the edited answer